# Automating the creation of a js object to Modify a HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, razor, automation

I'am quite new to javascript and generally web development, and this solution technically works but it does seem less than ideal.

Iam Currently working on a Project to create a small Website with razor pages.
Currently I have a quite long form with a lot of members.
This is the format:

```
<div class="container" id="formContainer">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm">
                <label>Ersatzteilname</label>
                <input asp-for="Part.Name" id="name">
            </div>
```

Simply a form with Modelbound Variables for the Inputs inside a container.

Now I have javascript code to make a js object bound to all the field of the form on the Website:

```
    let part = {
    name : document.getElementById("name"),
     field : document.getElementById("field"),
    factory : document.getElementById("factory"),
     magazine : document.getElementById("magazine"),
    shelf : document.getElementById("shelf"),
     frame : document.getElementById("frame"),
     compartment : document.getElementById("compartment"),
     box : document.getElementById("box"),
     machineList : document.getElementById("machineList"),
     supplier : document.getElementById("supplier"),
     supplierType : document.getElementById("supplierType"),
     supplierArticleNumber : document.getElementById("supplierArticleNumber"),
     manufacturer : document.getElementById("manufacturer"),
     comment : document.getElementById("comment"),
     minStock : document.getElementById("minStock"),
    stock : document.getElementById("stock"),
     targetStock : document.getElementById("targetStock"),
    price : document.getElementById("price"),
    unit : document.getElementById("unit"),
     abcClass : document.getElementById("abcClass"),
     orderAmount : document.getElementById("orderAmount"),
    pictureLink : document.getElementById("pictureLink"),
     wca : document.getElementById("wca"),
    edv_FUE : document.getElementById("edv_FUE"),
     calibration : document.getElementById("calibration"),
   status : document.getElementById("status"),
    }
```

The Object is used to later modify the form by fetching data from a SQL server using ajax.

Needless to say , assigning every form Field manually might work.. for one form. But it's tedious.
And would be horrible for Expand-ability

I've looked trough here and only found the ability so far to make a object in JS that uses my c# Model Class I use for the SQL server.

But besides that breaking Intellisense autocompletion , it also still leaves me with a similar task to above of having to assign all these variables to the specific form fields.

Any other way to possibly automate this?
If not would there be a way to say, make a macro in VS that would do it for me?

Comment: This is already provided for. see: [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me introduce you to arrays and how they can help you with repetitive tasks like the one you describe.

By putting all the names in an array, and using a for loop over that array, it can retrieve all the elements with very little code.

```js
const parts = [
  'name', 'field', 'factory', 'magazine', 'shelf', 'frame',
  'compartment', 'box', 'machineList', 'supplier', 'supplierType',
  'supplierArticleNumber', 'manufacturer', 'comment', 'minStock',
  'stock', 'targetStock', 'price', 'unit', 'abcClass', 'orderAmount',
  'pictureLink', 'wca', 'edv_FUE', 'calibration', 'status'
];

const obj = {};
for (const id of parts) {
  obj[id] = document.getElementById(id);
}
console.log(obj)
```

```html
<div id="name"></div>
<input id="factory">
```

However, the standard way to get values from a form is to use
[FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Setting the values ​​can be a bit more complicated depending on the data: It might not be in the right format, so some processing might be required.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');

function getData() {
  return new FormData(form);
}

function setData(data) {
  // A simplified method for setting values ​​from
  // an object, where the key is the name.
  // It doesn't set values ​​it doesn't know,
  // doesn't handle select elements that
  // don't have the required value, and so on...
  // It's just a simple example.
  for (const [name, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
    // get a list of all elements with the name
    for (const elem of elems = document.getElementsByName(name)) {
      if (elem.type === 'checkbox') {
        // if it's a checkbox, check if the value exists.
        elem.checked = value.indexOf(elem.value) >= 0
      } else {
        elem.value = value;
      }
    }
  }
}

form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const data = getData();
  // Converts to an array for display only.
  // Note how the checkboxes are handled. 
  console.log(Array.from(data));
});

btnSet.onclick = () => {
  setData({
    name:'Homer Simpson',
    service:['parking'],
    occupation:'Nuclear Technician'
  });
};
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}

label .label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}

label .field {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>
    <span class="label">Name</span>
    <span class="field"><input name="name"></span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <span class="label">Factory</span>
    <span class="field">
      <select name="factory">
        <option>Car Factory</option>
        <option>Computer Factory</option>
      </select>
    </span>
  </label>
  <formfield>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="service" value="parking"> Parking</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="service" value="gym"> Gym</label>
  </formfield>

  <button type="submit">Get Data</button>
</form>


<button id="btnSet" type="button">Set data</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! taking an array seems much cleaner and easier than Manually.

Thanks for the explanation of the Formadata usage  too! Altough my Project already is using razor page modelbinding for actully gettiung the values.